# Invalid behavior of __main__.py and __init__.py files

Tags: python, python-3.11

I am currently working on a Python package. The package can be imported or it can also run from command line with `-m` switch. Inside the package I am building a dependency injection container using - [python-dependency-injector](https://python-dependency-injector.ets-labs.org/).

Now, here is my understanding of the `__init__.py` and `__main__.py` files -

1. If package is imported - the content of `__init__.py` is executed.
2. If package is ran from command line with `-m` - the content of `__main__.py` is executed.

For me weirdly, in either cases content of both files is being executed. Either I import the package or run it from command line the control flows through `__init__.py` to `__main__.py` and so on. All I am doing inside these files is building the dependency injection container -

```
from .containers import Container
container = Container()
container.init_resources()
container.wire(packages=[__name__])
```

When I run the package from command line I also get a RunTimeWarning as  -
`RunTimeWarning: 'package.__main__.py' found in sys_modules after import of package 'package', but prior to execution of 'package.__main__'; this may result in unpredictable behavior`

And to fix this I added `del sys.modules['package.__main__']` in `__init__.py`.

Here is my folder structure -

```
src
  \package
     \__init__.py
     \__main__.py
     \readers
        \__init__.py
        \reader_module.py
     \writers
        \__init__.py
        \writer_module.py
     \utility
     \__init__.py
     \container_module.py
  test.py <-- imports the package
```

Comment: You do realize that doing `python -m package` will run `__init__.py` and THEN run `__main__.py`?  Are you importing `__main__`?

Comment: @TimRoberts nope I dint knew that. Please excuse my limited knowledge. Nope, I am not importing `__main__.py`. How I can restrict `__init__.py` run when I want to run my package from command line?

Comment: What is in `__init__.py`?

Comment: In general do not try to restrict execution in `__init__.py`. The `__init__.py` should do things important to use the module and it is called every time you want to to use the module for a reason. If you have things in `__init__.py` that break the execution when using `-m` then you probably need to redesign your package.

Comment: @TimRoberts Inside `__init__.py` i have container registeration code. Inside `__main__.py` I would be importing a module.

Comment: @Nopileos how I can restrict rhe execution of `__main__.py` when my package is imported?

Comment: When importing a package, the `__main__.py` won't be imported automatically. If it gets imported, there must be an explicit `import` (or equivalent)

Comment: @VPfB I am not importing `__main__.py` explicitly. My doubt is it may be getting loaded because of the dependency-injector package I am using.

Comment: @arpymastro (using lower level `importlib` functions is what I meant with "import equivalent"). You could debug what is pulling in the module in a quick&dirty way, just add temporarily a `raise ...` (`1/0` will do as well)  as the first statement of the `__main__.py` to get a traceback.

Comment: @VPfB I tried raising and it line - `container.wire(packages=[__name__])` causing the `__main__.py` to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that the dependency-injector package is causing to load `__main__.py` file when I import my package. Specifically, when the container is wired - `container.wire(packages=[__name__])`.|

For now, I have decided to keep `__main__.py` empty.